# Firebase Firestore Security Rule: touching resource.data in create rule always returns false

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to understand `resource.data` in Firestore's security rules, as there are some peculiarities with it in `create` rules. The following returns false:

```
allow create: if ('foo' in resource.data) || !('foo' in resource.data);
```

I believe it's because `resource.data` doesn't exist in a create operation, as the following 2 statements resolve to true:

```
allow create: if ('foo' in request.resource.data) || !('foo' in request.resource.data);
allow update: if ('foo' in resource.data) || !('foo' in resource.data);
```

Even this fails:

```
allow create: if debug(resource.data.size()) == 0;
```

Now you might be wondering why I need to touch `resource.data` in a create rule. It's because I'm working with the double duty `write` rule instead of a `create` rule, and any time `resource.data` is touched, I get unexpected results. I'm trying to see how I can detect a `create` operation inside of a `write` rule and apply the appropriate logic. Any way to do this?

Comment: Can you include an example of a write rule you are trying to implement and what you expect it to allow/deny?

Comment: The `resource.data` clause is going to be empty in a `create` indeed, but `request.resource.data` should contain the data you're writing (or more accurately: as it will exist after the write succeeds). Detecting a creation in the write rule should be something like: `!exists(resource)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, you lead me in the right direction. `!exists(resource)` doesn't work because `resource` is a map and `exists` expects a path. However, `resource == null` does work. I was trying `resource.data == null` and that was throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Well it turns out that the reason why `if ('foo' in resource.data) || !('foo' in resource.data);` doesn't evaluate to true is because `resource.data` is silently throwing an exception on create, and it forces the whole thing to evaluate to false. The way to check whether the rule is triggered by a `create` or `update` in a `write` rule is as simple as this:

```
resource == null // if true, it's create, otherwise, it's update
```

**2022-01-22 Update:**

There's a more semantic way to determine whether the operation was a create:

```
request.method == 'create'
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions

Comment: Good to hear you got it working, and thanks for sharing your solution 